# " SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" while interacting with smart contract using node instance

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Im trying to interact with my smart contract using web3js.

when i run js file using node instance i.e. node myfile.js

Im getting error like

```
undefined 1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/Documents/Project/miner1/requestor.js:234:19)
```

line 234 code is `var accAbi = JSON.parse(web3.utils.hexToAscii(accAbiBytes));`

Here is my code from line number 228

```
var methodName = "Method1";
var register = web3.eth.Contract(regAbi, regAddr);
var accAddr = register.methods.getContractAddr(methodName);
var accAbiBytes = web3.utils.bytesToHex(register.methods.getContractAbi(methodName));
//var accAbiBytes_new = web3.utils.utf8ToHex(accAbiBytes);
//console.log(web3.utils.isHex(accAbiBytes_new));
var accAbi = JSON.parse(web3.utils.hexToAscii(accAbiBytes));
```

can anybody help me. I tried some solutions in stackoverflow but nothing worked.

Comment: To begin with, add `await` before `register.methods`, and put everything inside an `async` function.

Comment: @goodvibration Im new to this stuff and javascript also. Can you send me  updated code . Thanks in adavance

Comment: No, and it won't get you much farther anyway, because you'll just stumble across another syntax problem. You need to learn the language syntax and understand how to resolve simple problems such as this one. For example, the error here tells you that the input to `JSON.parse` is wrong. You should have therefore checked what input you are passing to this function and investigate how this input is different from what the function expects.